# How to scroll a combobox's list to bring an option into view in Selenium php-webdriver?

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, combobox

I have a combobox that has a long list of options, resulting in the list having a scroll bar. I'd like Selenium to scroll one of the options that's currently hidden into view and click it, just like a user would do to select it. How do I go about doing that? I've tried calling the element's `getLocationOnScreenOnceScrolledIntoView()` method and `$webDriver->executeScript('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);', [$option])`, but neither worked. (The first one appears to scroll the page, rather than just the containing element; and the second one just doesn't seem to do anything.) The click just throws an ElementClickInterceptedException because the element that I want to click on (the option) is obscured by another element (the list's wrapper).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my failure to scroll an option into view was due to the way the combobox was constructed and not with what I was doing to scroll an option into view. (The options in the list were DIVs instead of LIs, and the test code was expecting the latter, so the list of options was coming back empty. After fixing the combobox, the `executeScript()` call in the question worked.)

**Update:** It turns out that you don't have to scroll a combobox option in a long list into view in order for Selenium to be able to click it.

**Further update:** It turns out that there may be cases where you do need to scroll the option into view in order to guarantee that it, and not another similar option, is the one that gets clicked on, so the safest way to go would be to do the scrolling using the `executeScript()` call in the question.